# How to address dynamic object keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I need to access object properties with dynamic keys which has persistent structure but different keys, like on one occasion it could be:

```
 var ty_tabs=[{
                "key1" :[{
                           "d1" : "v1",
                           "d2" : "v2",
                           "d3" : "v3"
                }],
                "key2" :[{
                           "d1" : "v1",
                           "d2" : "v2",
                           "d3" : "v3"
                }]
             }]
```

and on another one:

```
 var ty_tabs=[{
                "key3" :[{
                           "d1" : "v1",
                           "d2" : "v2",
                           "d3" : "v3"
                }],
                "key4" :[{
                           "d1" : "v1",
                           "d2" : "v2",
                           "d3" : "v3"
                }]
             }]
```

How do I adopt my code:

```
var b,a,d1,d2,d3;
for (b = 0 , a = ty_tabs.length; b < a ; ++b){
    d1 = ty_tabs[b].key1[0].d1;
    d2 = ty_tabs[b].key1[0].d2;
    d3 = ty_tabs[b].key1[0].d3;
}
```

To access properties with varying keys:

```
    d1 = ty_tabs[b].?[0].d1;
    d2 = ty_tabs[b].?[0].d2;
    d3 = ty_tabs[b].?[0].d3;
```

Comment: I have in JSON data ,array value as object as name array; this name array is dynamic value and this value have dynamic value.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know about the keys of an object, but need all keys present within an it, you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var b,a,d1,d2,d3, i, keys;
for (b = 0 , a = ty_tabs.length; b < a ; ++b){
    keys = Object.keys( ty_tabs[b] );

    for( i=0; i<keys.length; i++ ) {
      d1 = ty_tabs[b][ keys[i] ][0].d1;
      d2 = ty_tabs[b][ keys[i] ][0].d2;
      d3 = ty_tabs[b][ keys[i] ][0].d3;
    }
}
```

<sup>`Object.keys()` is rather well supported. For older versions of IE, you can use the [polyfill provided at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill)</sup>